# Insert a new section in UITableView

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I am developing an application that shows all the courses that take place in a class room depending on the time and date. In the prototype I was thinking to implement a UITableView, with two sections, one for previous clases(top) and one for next classes. I want to add the previous button as the header of the section with following classes and when I press it I want to programatically add a new section and populate it with the previous courses. I am not sure how to implement this, what methods I should override, etc.

I found something quite similar but I couldn't find any details of how he actually implemented it.

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to read up on UITableViews and the delegate methods. The sections are controlled in:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
```

You can put conditional logic here to control how many sections you need. Button pressed calls [tableView reloadData]; and will update the sections with it. How you control the data going into the table is up to you, but this should get you started.

Comment: I have read up on UITableViews but I am not sure if I have understood right. So when I press on my button, do I need to call - `(void)insertSections:(NSIndexSet *)sections withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation; ` and after that `[tableView reloadData]? ` and in  `(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView` I only put the logical condition?

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)sectionPreviousBunttonPress:(id)sender {
...
[sections addObject:section];
[courses addObjectsFromArray:fetchedCourses];
[table reloadData];
}
```